# encodeURIComponent not returns svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, imagemagick, encodeuricomponent

Hello Guys encodeURIComponent not returns my svg.

```
var svg ='<svg id="vgroovFrame" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="576" height="720"><defs> <pattern id="matpattern" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/a5/b7/e1a5b7edacee456a4f3bc3e00c3c01d9.jpg"/></pattern></defs><path d= M 82.29,164.57 C 82.29,164.57 164.57,164.57 164.57,82.29 L 164.57,82.29 411.43,82.29 C 411.43,82.29 411.43,164.57 493.71,164.57 L 493.71,164.57 493.71,555.43 C 493.71,555.43 411.43,555.43 411.43,637.71 L 411.43,637.71 164.57,637.71 C 164.57,637.71 164.57,555.43 82.29,555.43 L 82.29,555.43 82.29,164.57 L 82.29,164.57 0.00,164.57 0.00,0.00 0.00,596.57 L 0.00,596.57 82.29,596.57 82.29,596.57 82.29,596.57 C 82.29,596.57 123.43,596.57 123.43,637.71 C 123.43,637.71 123.43,678.86 82.29,678.86 C 82.29,678.86 41.14,678.86 41.14,637.71 C 41.14,637.71 41.14,596.57 82.29,596.57 L 82.29,596.57 0.00,596.57 0.00,720.00 452.57,720.00 452.57,637.71 C 452.57,637.71 452.57,596.57 493.71,596.57 C 493.71,596.57 534.86,596.57 534.86,637.71 C 534.86,637.71 534.86,678.86 493.71,678.86 C 493.71,678.86 452.57,678.86 452.57,637.71 L 452.57,637.71 452.57,720.00 576.00,720.00 576.00,123.43 493.71,123.43 C 493.71,123.43 452.57,123.43 452.57,82.29 C 452.57,82.29 452.57,41.14 493.71,41.14 C 493.71,41.14 534.86,41.14 534.86,82.29 C 534.86,82.29 534.86,123.43 493.71,123.43 L 493.71,123.43 576.00,123.43 576.00,0.00 123.43,0.00 123.43,82.29 C 123.43,82.29 123.43,123.43 82.29,123.43 C 82.29,123.43 41.14,123.43 41.14,82.29 C 41.14,82.29 41.14,41.14 82.29,41.14 C 82.29,41.14 123.43,41.14 123.43,82.29 L 123.43,82.29 123.43,0.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,164.57 " fill="#ff0000;" stroke="#f000" stroke-width="1px" style="fill:url(#matpattern)"/></path></svg>';

    data = encodeURIComponent(svg);
```

below is output of returns data

> %3Csvg%20id%3D%22vgroovFrame%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22576%22%20height%3D%22720%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%20%3Cpattern%20id%3D%22matpattern%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20patternUnits%3D%22userSpaceOnUse%22%3E%20%3Cimage%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.arttoframe.com%2Fproducts%2Fmats%2Fimages%2F200%2F61.jpg%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fpattern%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%20M%2082.29%2C164.57%20C%2082.29%2C164.57%20164.57%2C164.57%20164.57%2C82.29%20L%20164.57%2C82.29%20411.43%2C82.29%20C%20411.43%2C82.29%20411.43%2C164.57%20493.71%2C164.57%20L%20493.71%2C164.57%20493.71%2C555.43%20C%20493.71%2C555.43%20411.43%2C555.43%20411.43%2C637.71%20L%20411.43%2C637.71%20164.57%2C637.71%20C%20164.57%2C637.71%20164.57%2C555.43%2082.29%2C555.43%20L%2082.29%2C555.43%2082.29%2C164.57%20L%2082.29%2C164.57%200.00%2C164.57%200.00%2C0.00%200.00%2C596.57%20L%200.00%2C596.57%2082.29%2C596.57%2082.29%2C596.57%2082.29%2C596.57%20C%2082.29%2C596.57%20123.43%2C596.57%20123.43%2C637.71%20C%20123.43%2C637.71%20123.43%2C678.86%2082.29%2C678.86%20C%2082.29%2C678.86%2041.14%2C678.86%2041.14%2C637.71%20C%2041.14%2C637.71%2041.14%2C596.57%2082.29%2C596.57%20L%2082.29%2C596.57%200.00%2C596.57%200.00%2C720.00%20452.57%2C720.00%20452.57%2C637.71%20C%20452.57%2C637.71%20452.57%2C596.57%20493.71%2C596.57%20C%20493.71%2C596.57%20534.86%2C596.57%20534.86%2C637.71%20C%20534.86%2C637.71%20534.86%2C678.86%20493.71%2C678.86%20C%20493.71%2C678.86%20452.57%2C678.86%20452.57%2C637.71%20L%20452.57%2C637.71%20452.57%2C720.00%20576.00%2C720.00%20576.00%2C123.43%20493.71%2C123.43%20C%20493.71%2C123.43%20452.57%2C123.43%20452.57%2C82.29%20C%20452.57%2C82.29%20452.57%2C41.14%20493.71%2C41.14%20C%20493.71%2C41.14%20534.86%2C41.14%20534.86%2C82.29%20C%20534.86%2C82.29%20534.86%2C123.43%20493.71%2C123.43%20L%20493.71%2C123.43%20576.00%2C123.43%20576.00%2C0.00%20123.43%2C0.00%20123.43%2C82.29%20C%20123.43%2C82.29%20123.43%2C123.43%2082.29%2C123.43%20C%2082.29%2C123.43%2041.14%2C123.43%2041.14%2C82.29%20C%2041.14%2C82.29%2041.14%2C41.14%2082.29%2C41.14%20C%2082.29%2C41.14%20123.43%2C41.14%20123.43%2C82.29%20L%20123.43%2C82.29%20123.43%2C0.00%200.00%2C0.00%200.00%2C164.57%20%22%20fill%3D%22%23ff0000%3B%22%20stroke%3D%22%23f000%22%20stroke-width%3D%221px%22%20style%3D%22fill%3Aurl(%23matpattern)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E

this is complete code

```
var popupMatArr = self.getPopUpMatDesign(self.configuration.popupMatStringCode,self.configuration.popupMatStringTopCode,self.configuration.popupMatStringBottomCode, self.selectedColor2, self.selectedColor3, self.configuration.popupMat_appliedMat, parseFloat(self.configuration.cuts[$("#removeimg").attr("data-val")].w), parseFloat(self.configuration.cuts[$("#removeimg").attr("data-val")].h));
var    data1 = encodeURIComponent(popupMatArr.svg);
img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + data1;
img.onload = function() {
self.ctx.drawImage(img,
0, 0, 
popupMatArr.WD, 
popupMatArr.HT,
((parseFloat(self.configuration.glass['frameWidth']) - vgroovConfigArr.dt/parseFloat(self.configuration.ppi)) * parseFloat(self.configuration.ppi) )* self.scale,
((parseFloat(self.configuration.glass['frameWidth'])  - vgroovConfigArr.dt/parseFloat(self.configuration.ppi)) * parseFloat(self.configuration.ppi) )* self.scale,
popupMatArr.WD * self.scale,
popupMatArr.HT * self.scale,
);
}
```

This is Svg image before encodeURIComponent

```
<svg id="vgroovFrame" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="576" height="720">
<defs>
<pattern id="matpattern" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
<image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/a5/b7/e1a5b7edacee456a4f3bc3e00c3c01d9.jpg"></image>
</pattern>
</defs>
<path d=" M 82.29,164.57 C 82.29,164.57 164.57,164.57 164.57,82.29 L 164.57,82.29 411.43,82.29 C 411.43,82.29 411.43,164.57 493.71,164.57 L 493.71,164.57 493.71,555.43 C 493.71,555.43 411.43,555.43 411.43,637.71 L 411.43,637.71 164.57,637.71 C 164.57,637.71 164.57,555.43 82.29,555.43 L 82.29,555.43 82.29,164.57 L 82.29,164.57 0.00,164.57 0.00,0.00 0.00,596.57 L 0.00,596.57 82.29,596.57 82.29,596.57 82.29,596.57 C 82.29,596.57 123.43,596.57 123.43,637.71 C 123.43,637.71 123.43,678.86 82.29,678.86 C 82.29,678.86 41.14,678.86 41.14,637.71 C 41.14,637.71 41.14,596.57 82.29,596.57 L 82.29,596.57 0.00,596.57 0.00,720.00 452.57,720.00 452.57,637.71 C 452.57,637.71 452.57,596.57 493.71,596.57 C 493.71,596.57 534.86,596.57 534.86,637.71 C 534.86,637.71 534.86,678.86 493.71,678.86 C 493.71,678.86 452.57,678.86 452.57,637.71 L 452.57,637.71 452.57,720.00 576.00,720.00 576.00,123.43 493.71,123.43 C 493.71,123.43 452.57,123.43 452.57,82.29 C 452.57,82.29 452.57,41.14 493.71,41.14 C 493.71,41.14 534.86,41.14 534.86,82.29 C 534.86,82.29 534.86,123.43 493.71,123.43 L 493.71,123.43 576.00,123.43 576.00,0.00 123.43,0.00 123.43,82.29 C 123.43,82.29 123.43,123.43 82.29,123.43 C 82.29,123.43 41.14,123.43 41.14,82.29 C 41.14,82.29 41.14,41.14 82.29,41.14 C 82.29,41.14 123.43,41.14 123.43,82.29 L 123.43,82.29 123.43,0.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,164.57 " fill="#ff0000;" stroke="#f000" stroke-width="1px" style="fill:url(#matpattern)">
</path>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's just URI encoding. What's the problem?

Comment: @RobertLongson SVG not returns in image source after URI encoding

Comment: @RobertLongson Please check again my question now I edited my question and post to code also. 'img.src' not getting valid image source.

Comment: charset=utf-8 rather than just utf-8

Comment: Looks like the SVG image is the issue. Double check namespace & attribute values with w3c validator.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for suggestion but it still not working.

Comment: @emcconville I have updated my question with SVG image as well as I tested svg image w3c validator its working fine, but  after URI encoding its not returning valid data

Comment: you can't have an external image in an SVG you're going to use as an image, you need to convert the <image> element to use a data URI

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry for inconvenience but I doesn't understand. Please give me a example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#SVG

Comment: @RobertLongson I have used base64 encoder but its not working. please check this error. >>  `error on line 1 at column 79331: Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined`

Comment: Feel free to look this up yourself in future. All I did was type xlink namespace and pick a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank You So much. I just try with base64 image in pattern. It reflects on canvas. Once again thank you